# Visual Studio 2022 Mac M1 .NET 6, Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I am having an issue with .NET 6 on Visual Studio 2022 Mac M1 chip. What happens is when I want to build or clean my WebApi project I get the following error.

```
The operation failed due to an internal error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

This is what I have for  **dotnet --info** command

```
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   6.0.200
 Commit:    4c30de7899

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Mac OS X
 OS Version:  12.2
 OS Platform: Darwin
 RID:         osx.12-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/sdk/6.0.200/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 6.0.2
  Commit:  839cdfb0ec

.NET SDKs installed:
  3.1.416 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/sdk]
  5.0.405 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/sdk]
  6.0.102 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/sdk]
  6.0.200 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.22 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.14 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.2 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.22 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.14 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.2 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]`

To install additional .NET runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

I have tried many things but none of them has worked. I would appricate any help!

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem.

Comment: Try to create a new asp.net core web application and check whether it build and run success? If still meet the same issue, perhaps there have a missing or corrupted file within your VS installation, you could try to repair the VS and reinstall it.

Comment: Thanks guys for your comments! I have tried that many times with no success. I reinstalled the VS, reinstalled the .Net sdk none of them helped. I tired to install the Microsoft.Build with NuGet and i also got the same error. I have seen people run it on Youtube without any issues:(

Comment: MSBuild is the build platform for Microsoft and Visual Studio. In the Visual Studio installer, navigate to Individual Components, and locate the checkbox for MSBuild. It is automatically selected when you choose any of the other workloads to install. If still not working, since this issue relates the Visual studio, I suggest you could post your question on the Visual Studio forum, like [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoftbuild-ver-1/399250).

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. And I have a clue (actually two), @Ner, if you'd like to test. 
First: Only dotnet 6 is supported by Microsoft on M1 Macs. So, if your project targets dotnet 5, it seems it won't work using only the sdk provided by the VSPreview installer.
Second: I think my VSPreview was trying to load packages using the dotnet from the x64 folder. So I removed all sdks from my machine and installed only the one from the VSPreview installer (dotnet6). Then the packages were correctly loaded.
Let me know if any of this works, then I add as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I change the setting the SDK location from

```
/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/dotnet
```

to

```
/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue and I was able to make it work. (also Mac M1 chip)

But I did several actions, I'm not sure which one was responsible for fixing it.

I think my problem was related to having both "Visual Studio 2019 for Mac" and "Visual Studio 2022 Preview for Mac" installed.

I've uninstalled both.
Then I removed all SDK files cleaning both:

```
/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64
```

and

```
/usr/local/share/dotnet/
```

(YMMV here, I used [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/remove-runtime-sdk-versions?pivots=os-macos#uninstall-net) to discover those paths)

Then I installed only the "Visual Studio 2022 Preview for Mac", with its net6.0 sdk.

Opened my solution and it didn't work (because my solution was net5.0).

Then I installed the old "Visual Studio 2019 for Mac" (to get the x64 net5.0 sdk installed).

And when I opened the solution in the new "VS 2022 Preview", it now worked.

At a given moment, I updated the .NET Core SDK location on Preferences:

[image: VSPreview Preferences, then SDK Locations, then .net core]

To /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
(which I think is the location for the net6)

I know my answer is not precise, but I count on the community help to test these steps and then I can edit it here. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Net Sdk for Arm64, you need to change the path for dotnet to

```
/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/dotnet/
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/macos#path-conflicts